# Flutter Horizontal Scroll is not working inside the overlay and dialogue

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying show overlay or dialogue in which we can select the item. But I am able to show items on overlay using listview but it will not able to scroll horizontally. I have tried different approach but nothing works.

```
void _insertOverlay(BuildContext context) {
    late OverlayEntry _overlay;
    _overlay = OverlayEntry(builder: (ctx) {
      final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
      print(size.width);
      return Material(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          children: [
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => _overlay.remove(),
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.grey.withAlpha(150),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned.fill(
              child: Container(
                width: 500,
                height: 500,
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: Scrollbar(
                  interactive: true,
                  thickness: 20,
                  // thumbVisibility: true,
                  trackVisibility: true,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                      itemCount: 10,
                      itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                        return getpriceItem();
                      })),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    });
    return Overlay.of(context)?.insert(_overlay);
  }
```

I am calling it here

```
Container(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  // shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  color: Colors.red),
              child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () => _insertOverlay(context),
                  child: const Center(child: Text('1'))),
              //height: 75.0,
              //width: 75.0,
            )
```

I am getting following error

```
The following assertion was thrown during a scheduler callback:
A ScrollController is required when Scrollbar.thumbVisibility is true. The Scrollbar was not provided a ScrollController, and attempted to use the PrimaryScrollController, but none was found.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/scrollbar.dart':
package:flutter/…/widgets/scrollbar.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 1468 pos 7: 'scrollController != null'
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error shows, your `scrollbar` is missing a `controller`. Try as follows:

```
  final ScrollController _firstController = ScrollController();
```

And

```
    Scrollbar(
                controller: _firstController
                // your code
              )
```